# How to bind to a signal from a delegate component within a ListView in QML

Tags: listview, qml, signals-slots

Let's say I have a `ListView` of clickable delegate components (or `GridView` or `Repeater`). These delegate components need to emit a signal along with custom data when triggered that can be picked up by the parent of the `ListView`. How can this signal binding be achieved?

e.g. The following code is my attempt but I don't know how to bind the `trigger` signal of the delegate component to the `componentTriggered` signal in the `root` item?

```
Item {
    id: root
    anchors.fill: parent

    signal componentTriggered(string name)

    onComponentTriggered: {
        console.log(name + ' component was triggered')
    }

    ListModel {
        id: myModel

        ListElement { name: "alpha" }
        ListElement { name: "beta" }
        ListElement { name: "gamma" }
        ListElement { name: "delta" }
    }

    ListView {
        id: myListView
        width: 100
        height: 600

        model: myModel
        delegate: TheDelegate { name: model.name }
    }
}
```

which accesses `TheDelegate.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 100
    height: 50
    color: "steelblue"
    border.color: "white"
    border.width: 2

    property string name

    signal trigger(string name)

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: model.name
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(root.name + ' clicked')
            root.trigger(root.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could connect both signals in the `Component.onCompleted` handler.

Using your code it would be something like this:

```
ListView {
        id: myListView
        width: 100
        height: 600

        model: myModel
        delegate: TheDelegate {
            name: model.name
            Component.onCompleted: {
                trigger.connect(root.componentTriggered)
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of calling the signal `componentTriggered` you could also implement a function, but it depends on your requirements. The signal is OK in any case.

Comment: That is truly awesome. Thank you. I hadn't realised you could essentially extend a component in the process of instantiating it or assigning it.