# Signal between QML with Repeater

Tags: connection, qml, signals, repeater

I have the following qml files, the main.qml creates TestWindow.qml elements.

I would like to connect a signal in TestWindow.qml (click on a button mySignalToMainWindow() ) to a function in main.qml, testConnection().

main.qml

```
Window {
    id: _component

    property int instances: 3

    width: 200
    height: Screen.height / 2
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        x = 40
        y = 40
    }

    Repeater {
        id: _windows
        model: instances
        TestWindow {
            index: model.index
            leftOffset: _component.width
        }
    }

    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: instances
            Button {
                text: "Window " + index
                onClicked:{ _windows.itemAt(index).window.raise();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function testConnection(){console.log("Subwindow To Main Window")}
}
```

And TestWindow.qml :

```
Item {
    id: _windowItem
    property int index
    property int leftOffset
    property alias window: _window
    signal mySignalToMainWindow()

    Window {
        id: _window

        visible: true
        title: "SubWindowText " + index

        Component.onCompleted: {
            x = leftOffset
            y = 40
            width = Screen.width - leftOffset
            height = Screen.height / 2
        }

        Text {
            id: windowText
            text: qsTr("SubWindowText")
        }

        Button {
            text: "SubWindow " + index
            onClicked: {console.log("TestWindow::Button onClicked "+_window);
                _windowItem.mySignalToMainWindow();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tested those two :

[How to bind to a signal from a delegate component within a ListView in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082678/how-to-bind-to-a-signal-from-a-delegate-component-within-a-listview-in-qml)
and
[How to access dynamically/randomly loaded Repeater items in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111218/how-to-access-dynamically-randomly-loaded-repeater-items-in-qml)

with no success.
So, how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple options there. The first is to define the binding, when creating the `Component` for the delegate:

```
Repeater {
    id: _windows
    model: instances
    TestWindow {
        index: model.index
        leftOffset: _component.width
        onMySignalToMainWindow: testConnection() <--- Here you can connect it.
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the `onItemAdded` and `onItemRemoved`-Handlers and connect the function there (`mySignalToMainWindow.connect(functionToConnect)`) and the respective `disconnect`, when it gets destroyed.

I'd recommend the former, if you want the connection to be permanent, and the latter if you might want to disconnect at some time.

The `onItemAdded/onRemoved` handlers are especially important if you don't declare a `delegate` for the `Repeater`. This happens for example if you use a `DelegateModel` or an `ObjectModel`. As with those models, you can't be sure, the objects are instantiated or destroyed when the `Repeater` adds or removes them, you could not use the often mentioned: `Component.onCompleted/onDestruction`, so I consider the `itemAdded/Removed`-signals superior/more general for the use with a `Repeater`.